# Image loads too slow with header()

Tags: php

I am using a php file which also loads an image. I am using header("location url") to load the image.

My problem is that the image is loading very slowly.  If I load it normally, it is much faster.

If I use JavaScript and put the code in the header to load the image, the image loads fast, but then I can't display the picture as an image.

Is there a way to speed the loading time up?

Thanks !

Comment: The only thing you're doing is to do a redirect so the only thing you're waiting for is another HTTP request. That might be bad on a slow network, but usually that falls under micro-optimization.

Comment: `header()` is not how you load an image. Your question does not have enough information.

Answer (score 1):

Try like this...

```
header("Content-Type: image/jpeg");
readfile("image.jpg");
```